Retry celery tasks which got killed on k8s pod termination
We are using celery(v5.4.0) for long (CPU intensive) tasks with Redis as the broker & backend. Our setup runs on kubernetes with auto-scaling based on CPU utilization.
The problem is when the pods scale down due to low utilization, some of the tasks which were being processed inside the pod are being killed and are not being re-queued on the active pods.
To solve this issue to an extent, we have set a terminationGracePeriodSeconds to a generous number. However, there are a few tasks which lie on the outlier in terms of processing time and they get killed.
We are also using acks_late=True and reject_on_worker_lost=True so that the task gets acknowledged after processing is complete and incase the pod dies, the task is re-queued.
Unfortunately this is not working the way we intended.
Here is a sample of the task setup. To simulate a pod being killed, we tried running the celery workers as 2 docker containers and killed one of them while it was executing the tasks. The tasks which got terminated due to the SIGKILL were not re-queued on the healthy container.
@celery_worker.task(
    name="primitive-task",
    bind=True,
    ignore_result=False,
    reject_on_worker_lost=True,
    acks_late=True,
)
def _add_task(self, x: int, y: int, task_id: int) -> int:
    sleep_time = random.randint(5, 10)

    print(
        f"[PID: {os.getpid()}]add task sleeping for {sleep_time} seconds for"
        f" {x=} | {y=} | {task_id=}"
    )
    time.sleep(sleep_time)

    print(f"result for {x=} | {y=} is {x+y} | {task_id=}")
    return x + y


Sounds like you are trying to have the cake and eat it. HPA should only be used for stateless applications. It is not a problem with your code, and you cannot do anything against that. When k8s decides to scale down, it will eventually send a sigkill to PID 1. You could try to intercept SIGKILL - but that is a Very Bad Idea ™, if you ask me.

What you could do is to add a MQ to the mix requiring explicit acknowledgement and only ack the respective task message after the task is done. Afaik, the Redis brokers implementation of celery does not support acknowledgement at all, so it is not suitable for your use case.
